# AT Commands HTTP request to JSON source with status 200 but empty response

Tags: json, arduino, httpresponse, at-command, sim900

I am working with an Arduino Mega and a SIM900 GSM/GPRS shield to make a get request against my own API.

I am using the following AT Commands, the module executes the request, but I receive a 200 response code without a body/response.

Here is my code:

```
AT+SAPBR=3,1,"Contype","GPRS"
AT+SAPBR=3,1,"APN","my.apn.com"
AT+SAPBR=1,1
AT+SAPBR=2,1
AT+HTTPPARA="CID",1
AT+HTTPPARA="URL","wbs-api.eu-gb.cf.appdomain.cloud/stats"

AT+HTTPACTION=0
-> 0,200,0 (as output of the command)
```

As far as I know, the last 0 stands for the size of the response body in bytes.

If I further execute

```
AT+HTTPREAD
->
```

Nothing is displayed.

Where has my answer disappeared to and why is it empty?

*Note:* I'm actually able to successful obtain data performing a request to a different server, but I noticed that the working request returns HTML code and not JSON data.

Comment: Shouldn't the URL start with `http://`? You also mistyped `HTTPPARA`.

Comment: Hey,  it makes No differece if the url starts with http:// or not. It also gives me the empty response. And yes of course, there is a P missing, just a error from copying.

Comment: Are you able to perform a GET  from any other page?

Comment: Yes, but i notized, that the other (working) request returns html code and not a jsons. Could that be a problem?

Comment: isn't this a problem of your response page, rather than your script?

Comment: @NiklasUllmann have you tried what I suggest in my answer?

Comment: Sorry not yet, I have no access to my sim900 module until monday evening. After that I will give you some feedback. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### TL;DR

Configure the accepted content type with

```
AT+HTTPPARA="CONTENT","application/json"
```

---

### Issue analysis

Since you are admittedly able to receive data from different sites, it means that the issue must be something specific to the address you are accessing.

The difference actually resides in the **application type**, as you are downloading **JSON data**. The following image shows the Wireshark capture of the response got from the server:

[image: HTTP response]

```
Content-type: application/json
```

But was the request some way "special"? The following image shows the Wireshark capture of the request sent to the server from my browser:

[image]

```
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8\r\n
```

So we can understand how that's probably a matter of *accepted type*.

---

### The solution: content type on SIM900 module

The command for specifying HTTP parameters in Simcom modules (see [Simcom AT Commands guide](https://simcom.ee/documents/SIM900/SIM900_AT%20Command%20Manual_V1.11.pdf)) is `AT+HTTPPARA`, that you already use in your script. Its syntax is

```
AT+HTTPPARA=<HTTPParamTag>,<HTTPParamValue>[<UserdataDelimiter>]
```

There are several allowed values for `HTTPParamTag` parameter, but one of the options is

> **"CONTENT"**
> Used  to  set  the  “Content-Type”  field  in  HTTP  header

For this reason the command

```
AT+HTTPPARA="CONTENT","application/json"
```

should make the trick. Just make sure that your FW version supports it. If not, update the FW version to the most recent one.